# Gitlab CI not able to use pg_prove

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm struggling to get a Gitlab CI up and running that uses the correct version of postgres (13) and has PGTap installed.

I deploy my project locally using a Dockerfile which uses `postgres:13.3-alpine` and then installs PGTap too. However, I'm not sure if I can use this Dockerfile to help with my CI issues.

In my gitlab-ci.yml file, I currently have:

```
variables:
 GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

pgtap:
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_request
      - master
    changes:
      - ddl/**/*
  image: postgres:13.1-alpine
  services:
    - name: postgres:13.1-alpine
      alias: db
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - psql postgres://postgres@db/postgres -c 'create extension pgtap;'
    - psql postgres://postgres@db/postgres -f ddl/01.sql
    - cd ddl/
    - psql postgres://postgres@db/postgres -f 02.sql
    - psql postgres://postgres@db/postgres -f 03.sql
    - pg_prove -d postgres://postgres@db/postgres --recurse test_*
```

The above works until it gets to the `pg_prove` command at the bottom as I get the below error:

```
pg_prove: command not found
```

Is there a way I can install pg_prove using the script commands? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it intentionally that you start two database servers?

Comment: No, that is not intentional - is that happening because I have the service the same as the image?

Comment: Yes, you are starting two containers that are linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old issue [closed](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/306).

To summarize, either you build you own image based on `postgres:13.1-alpine` installing PGTap or you use a non official [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/1maa/postgres/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) where PGTap is installed `1maa/postgres:13-alpine` :

```
docker run -it 1maa/postgres:13-alpine sh
/ # which pg_prove
/usr/local/bin/pg_prove
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your step image is alpine based, you can try:

```
script:
 - apk add --no-cache --update build-base make perl perl-dev git openssl-dev
 - cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP
 - psql.. etc
```

You can probably omit some of the packages...